# Incorrect entry written to file

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm writing a flask app for someone to curate my dataset. It's supposed to show a tweet in a textarea, and the person selects options on a radio button and submits it, and it is written into a file. However, the problem is that the tweet show in the textarea is not the same one written into the file. If tweet A is shown in the text area, the next tweet, tweet B, is written to the file, even though the person rated tweet A. What is going wrong? My html template and flask code are below:

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import csv
app = Flask(__name__)
with open('sqldata.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        data = [row for row in reader]
x = []
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
        datapoint = data[len(x)+1][2]
        db={'Entry':datapoint}
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print request.form['Button1']
            but1 = request.form['Button1']
            but2 = request.form['Button2']
            print sent
            but3 = request.form['Button3']
            with open('path/%s.csv' % but2, 'a') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerows([(datapoint, but1)])
            with open('path/data.csv', 'a') as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow([but3])
            x.append(len(x))
        return render_template('index.html', db=db)
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host, port,debug=True)
```

HTML template:

```
<html>
    <head> Sentiment Analysis Dataset</head>
    <style>
    .scrollabletextbox {
height:50px;
width:200px;
font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 82%;
overflow:scroll;
    }
    </style>
    <form method='POST'>
            <b> Unclassified Text </b>
            <textarea class='scrollabletextbox' name='Text' readonly>
            {{db.Entry}}
            </textarea>
            <br>
            <b> But2 </b> <br>
            Positive:<input type='radio' name='Button2' value='1'><br>
            Negative:<input type='radio' name = 'Button2' value='2'><br>
            Noise:<input type='radio' name = 'Button2' value = '3'><br>
            1<input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='1'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='2'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='3'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='4'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='5'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='6'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='7'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='8'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='9'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='10'>10<br>
            <b>But3</b><br>
            <input type='text' name='Button3'><br>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='Submit'>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form contains no elements called `Button1` or `Button2` or `Button3`...

Comment: I edited it in, sorry

Comment: No problem. What does `print but3` give you?

Comment: The user inputs something like A-B,B-C in that form, so it prints out exactly that. I think the problem with my code is that the post method searches for the next tweet while the get method has already populated the form with something, thus causing that initial offset. But I can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: Tried that, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the value in the textarea to update your data files. Please see tested code below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import csv, os
import jinja2

app = Flask(__name__)

with open('sqldata.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [row for row in reader]

x = []
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    datapoint = data[len(x)][2]
    db={'Entry':datapoint}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        but1 = request.form['Button1']
        but2 = request.form['Button2']
        but3 = request.form['Button3']
        with open('%s.csv' % but2,'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows([(request.form['Text'], but1)])
        with open('data.csv','a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow([but3])
        x.append(len(x))
    return render_template('index.html',db=db)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates'))
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Template code:

```
<html>
    <head> Sentiment Analysis Dataset</head>
    <style>
    .scrollabletextbox {
height:50px;
width:200px;
font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 82%;
overflow:scroll;
    }
    </style>
    <form method='POST'>
            <b> Unclassified Text</b>
            <textarea class='scrollabletextbox' name='Text'>{{db.Entry}}</textarea>
            <br>
            <b> But2 </b> <br>
            Positive:<input type='radio' name='Button2' value='1'><br>
            Negative:<input type='radio' name = 'Button2' value='2'><br>
            Noise:<input type='radio' name = 'Button2' value = '3'><br>
            1<input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='1'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='2'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='3'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='4'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='5'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='6'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='7'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='8'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='9'>
            <input type='radio' name = 'Button1' value='10'>10<br>
            <b>But3</b><br>
            <input type='text' name='Button3'><br>
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='Submit'>
    </form>
</html>
```